# How to scroll with mouse in terminal when using nano

Tags: command-line, mouse

I just set up an ubuntu machine. When I open a file using nano, I need to use the arrow keys to scroll through the file. When I use the mouse to scroll it doesn't scroll down, but scrolling up brings up the previously typed commands. How can I adjust the scroll to only scroll the file instead of the entire terminal window?

I guess this question doesn't apply to just `nano`, but any other tool that opens up a separate document for reading, say `man` pages?

Answer (score 1):

I found something on [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37980004/scroll-using-the-mouse-in-nano-editor#:%7E:text=Nano%20doesn%27t%20support%20using,if%20available%20for%20your%20system.):

> Nano doesn't support using the mouse wheel to scroll. You can enable nano's (limited) mouse support with alt-M or with --mouse when starting nano (another invocation returns to whatever mouse support your terminal has), but that's it: